# Nothing happens when trying to post an ad to Kijiji with Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I've been trying to post an add to Kijiji with Python's `requests` module but it seems I can't get anything to actually happen, I've also tried this library https://github.com/adrienverge/kijijiapi but to no avail.

Here's what I have so far:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    kijiji_login_data = {"ca.kijiji.xsrf.token": "1537280029833.544492f64f2e13fa63e353710a635eb551492aaa2a25b1e8cbe6f4dd35eae5a0",
                    "targetUrl": "L15udS9JWHhHMURBNmdjdkFuTFJJeUR3PT0-",
                    'emailOrNickname': "....",
                    "password:": "....",
                    "rememberMe": "true",
                    "_rememberMe": "on"
    }

    kijiji_login_headers = {"authority": "www.kijiji.ca",
    "method": "POST",
    "path": "/t-login.html",
    "scheme": "https",
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'content-length': '241',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'cookie': 'machId=60bb3d625f99f97619ec54aeed7c6c211cb37432c234969bf7fb4025e7130f9c69f1622f09f6b75066c73a04e8cddb80d8491eee4fe5a9bf4a08aed0bfb59cfa; cguid=Vcguid=8eb289531640ab6be117f53dfc1ab836^doml=true^brl=true; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1531402425818r0.8162488354397672; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%7D; _ga=GA1.2.633052862.1531402426; cto_lwid=ae6adb61-bce7-4cbb-8cba-9741b931e078; fab=0; ab=1; AAMC_kijiji_0=REGION%7C7; kjses=1b53034f-529e-4655-bb54-662578067dd3^jXn6l1b/xd0qwb/VcB9vBw==; siteLocale=en_CA; aam_uuid=69770583923959576153366449441674094698; suid_1370960782=2t3xn9dne; suid_1372038453=ugnfj0x2; suid_1368134801=i95zds08; suid_1380855099=2k0g6d48e; suid_1377346581=37yeeemrx; suid_1380161212=fprfr4aa; rememberMe=Vrme=true; optimizelySegments=%7B%222206171013%22%3A%22referral%22%2C%222211990585%22%3A%22gc%22%2C%222212760107%22%3A%22none%22%2C%222219751317%22%3A%22false%22%2C%226842320387%22%3A%22true%22%7D; ki_r=; ad_ids_s=Vsaved_s=; _gid=GA1.2.2018386389.1537195364; userEmail=charles@germanstarmotors.ca; kjrva=; up=%7B%22ln%22%3A%22615773491%22%2C%22ls%22%3A%22l%3D1700273%26sv%3DLIST%26sf%3DdateDesc%22%2C%22rva%22%3A%221368852193%2C1367353454%2C1348137031%2C1362992124%2C1373169737%2C1373166912%2C1364622944%2C1370918761%2C1373102575%2C1366846075%2C1371455350%2C1363082440%2C1372925986%2C1370960782%2C1372038453%2C1368134801%2C1380855099%2C1377346581%2C1380161212%2C1384545277%22%7D; JSESSIONID=45504ACFCDFFE2FD7D28DD7537D4CF30; optimizelyPendingLogEvents=%5B%5D; _gat=1; ki_t=1531402426979%3B1537279967903%3B1537280031280%3B12%3B119; algoliaToken=eyJhcGlLZXkiOiJOVGt6WVRNNVpURTNNRFJtTkRjd1lqa3lOV1psWTJRNU56TXlPVGRtWVRJek9HTTVOek00TVdKak5HVmlOMlV6TWpreE5XUmpZV1k1T1RWak5tWTNZM1poYkdsa1ZXNTBhV3c5TVRVek56TTJOalEwTVRBeE13PT0iLCJhcHBJZCI6IjNJRDc4WU1PV1UiLCJpbmRleCI6ImtjYV9wcm9kX3N1Z2dlc3QiLCJ2YWxpZFVudGlsIjoxNTM3MzY2NDQxMDEzfQ==; _gali=SignInButton',
    'origin': 'https://www.kijiji.ca',
    'referer': 'https://www.kijiji.ca/t-login.html',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36}'
               }


    kijiji_post_data = {
        'ca.kijiji.xsrf.token': '1537285126338.356568b2ee1a221db2b8af988efb3cc6ee5c4480fd1f83f4ad462c534db74c92',
            'images':'',
    'postAdForm.fraudToken': 'f9e506b3012a0b51ce4d3781e143f18f',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[vin_s]':'',
    'postAdForm.vinExploded': '1',
    'yesVIN':'',
    'haveVIN':'',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[carprooflink_s]':'',
    'postAdForm.carproof': 'NONE',
    'uuid':'',
    'adId':'',
    'postAdForm.galleryImageIndex':'',
    'postAdForm.geocodeLat': '43.936904',
    'postAdForm.geocodeLng': '-78.83649479999997',
    'postAdForm.city': 'Pinecrest',
    'postAdForm.province': '',
    'PostalLat': '',
    'PostalLng': '',
    'categoryId': '174',
    'postAdForm.locationId': '1700275',
    'postAdForm.mapAddress': 'Oshawa, ON L1K 2S9',
    'postAdForm.postalCode': 'L1K 2S9',
    'postAdForm.showLocationOnMap': 'false',
    'postAdForm.saveLocation': 'true',
    'postAdForm.mapRadius': '164.16673067907342',
    'postAdForm.adType': 'OFFER',
    'postAdForm.priceType': 'FIXED',
    'postAdForm.priceAmount': '100',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[forsaleby_s]': 'ownr',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[carmake_s]': 'acura',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[carmodel_s]': 'cl',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[cartrim_s]': '',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[carbodytype_s]': 'coup',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[caryear_i]': '2000',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[vehicletype_s': 'used',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[carmileageinkms_i]': '200000',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[cartransmission_s]':'',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[drivetrain_s]':'',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[carcolor_s]':'',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[carfueltype_s]':'',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[stock_s]':'',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[noofdoors_s]':'',
    'postAdForm.attributeMap[noofseats_s]':'',
    'postAdForm.title': '1999 Acura CL Coupe (2 door)',
    'postAdForm.description': 'good car in good shape',
    'file':'',
    'postAdForm.youtubeVideoURL':'',
    'postingLocation': '1700275',
    'postAdForm.phoneNumber':'',
    'featuresForm.featurePackage': 'PKG_BASIC',
    'file':'',
    'featuresForm.topAdDuration': '7',
    'featuresForm.carProofReportType': 'VERIFIED',
    'submitType': 'saveAndCheckout',
    }

    kijiji_post_headers = {
    'authority': 'www.kijiji.ca',
    'method': 'POST',
    'path': '/p-submit-ad.html',
    'scheme': 'https',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'content-length': '1781',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'cookie': 'machId=60bb3d625f99f97619ec54aeed7c6c211cb37432c234969bf7fb4025e7130f9c69f1622f09f6b75066c73a04e8cddb80d8491eee4fe5a9bf4a08aed0bfb59cfa; cguid=Vcguid=8eb289531640ab6be117f53dfc1ab836^doml=true^brl=true; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1531402425818r0.8162488354397672; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%7D; _ga=GA1.2.633052862.1531402426; cto_lwid=ae6adb61-bce7-4cbb-8cba-9741b931e078; fab=0; ab=1; AAMC_kijiji_0=REGION%7C7; kjses=1b53034f-529e-4655-bb54-662578067dd3^jXn6l1b/xd0qwb/VcB9vBw==; siteLocale=en_CA; aam_uuid=69770583923959576153366449441674094698; suid_1370960782=2t3xn9dne; suid_1372038453=ugnfj0x2; suid_1368134801=i95zds08; suid_1380855099=2k0g6d48e; suid_1377346581=37yeeemrx; suid_1380161212=fprfr4aa; rememberMe=Vrme=true; optimizelySegments=%7B%222206171013%22%3A%22referral%22%2C%222211990585%22%3A%22gc%22%2C%222212760107%22%3A%22none%22%2C%222219751317%22%3A%22false%22%2C%226842320387%22%3A%22true%22%7D; ki_r=; ad_ids_s=Vsaved_s=; _gid=GA1.2.2018386389.1537195364; userEmail=charles@germanstarmotors.ca; _gcl_au=1.1.822933308.1537283481; up=%7B%22ln%22%3A%22615773491%22%2C%22ls%22%3A%22l%3D1700273%26sv%3DLIST%26sf%3DdateDesc%22%2C%22rva%22%3A%221367353454%2C1348137031%2C1362992124%2C1373169737%2C1373166912%2C1364622944%2C1370918761%2C1373102575%2C1366846075%2C1371455350%2C1363082440%2C1372925986%2C1370960782%2C1372038453%2C1368134801%2C1380855099%2C1377346581%2C1380161212%2C1384545277%2C1384754333%22%7D; kjrva=; ssid=MTAxNDQwNjkxM3xleUowZVhBaU9pSktWMVFpTENKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpVeE1pSjkuZXlKbGVIQWlPakUxTmpnNE1qQTNOVFFzSW1saGRDSTZNVFV6TnpJNE5EYzFOQ3dpYzNWaUlqb2lNVEF4TkRRd05qa3hNeUlzSW1WdFlXbHNJam9pWTJoaGNteGxjMEJuWlhKdFlXNXpkR0Z5Ylc5MGIzSnpMbU5oSW4wLlVTWWpjaTNYZ2FHVlFMVmF5VXBVaGlkRTE3LUYtcEU4bDNYRFdGaDdtS1BNWlBaR21JdWlfV3N2WWd6blE1RVlQWjBicHprV2hSLXZoMEp4VW03MFdB; algoliaToken=eyJhcGlLZXkiOiJPR014Tm1VNE1qTmlOemt6WmpjMU5XRmlaRGsyT0RFM1pXVm1PRGhqT0RVNU5qQXlPRFppWmpNNVlqVTVNVEE1TVRRM04yRmtPR0l4TVRZME5UYzVOWFpoYkdsa1ZXNTBhV3c5TVRVek56TTNNVEV6TkRreU1BPT0iLCJhcHBJZCI6IjNJRDc4WU1PV1UiLCJpbmRleCI6ImtjYV9wcm9kX3N1Z2dlc3QiLCJ2YWxpZFVudGlsIjoxNTM3MzcxMTM0OTIwfQ==; JSESSIONID=0C7B57A29C37B1B2BBAD243EEB79E25D; ki_t=1531402426979%3B1537279967903%3B1537285127774%3B12%3B140; _gat=1; _gali=MainForm',
    'origin': 'https://www.kijiji.ca',
    'referer': 'https://www.kijiji.ca/p-post-ad.html?categoryId=174&adTitle=car+for+sale',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'
    }

    s = requests.Session()
    #login to kijiji
    login = s.post('https://www.kijiji.ca/t-login.html', data=kijiji_login_data, headers=kijiji_login_headers)
    #post an ad
    make_post = s.post('https://www.kijiji.ca/p-submit-ad.html', data=kijiji_post_data, headers=kijiji_post_headers)
```

When I test the response I do indeed get a `200` status code, but the ad isn't there. I'm not sure what else to do?

Comment: Both `login.status_code` and `make_post.status_code` have a 200 code in IT?

Comment: Yes they do, if I remove credentials like the password completely I'll get a 500 error code. But if I submit the wrong password I get a 200 still